# Scala map and/or groupby functions

Tags: scala, dictionary, grouping

I am new to Scala and I am trying to figure out some scala syntax.

So I have a list of strings.

```
wordList: List[String] = List("this", "is", "a", "test")
```

I have a function that returns a list of pairs that contains consonants and vowels counts per word:

```
def countFunction(words: List[String]): List[(String, Int)]
```

So, for example:

```
countFunction(List("test")) => List(('Consonants', 3), ('Vowels', 1))
```

I now want to take a list of words and group them by count signatures:

```
def mapFunction(words: List[String]): Map[List[(String, Int)], List[String]]

//using wordList from above
mapFunction(wordList) => List(('Consonants', 3), ('Vowels', 1)) -> Seq("this", "test")
                         List(('Consonants', 1), ('Vowels', 1)) -> Seq("is")
                         List(('Consonants', 0), ('Vowels', 1)) -> Seq("a")
```

I'm thinking I need to use GroupBy to do this:

```
def mapFunction(words: List[String]): Map[List[(String, Int)], List[String]] = { 
    words.groupBy(F: (A) => K)
}
```

I've read the scala api for Map.GroupBy and see that F represents discriminator function and K is the type of keys you want returned. So I tried this:

```
    words.groupBy(countFunction => List[(String, Int)]
```

However, scala doesn't like this syntax. I tried looking up some examples for groupBy and nothing seems to help me with my use case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, your count function should take a word instead of a list of words. I would have defined it like this:

```
def countFunction(words: String): List[(String, Int)]
```

If you do that you should be able to call `words.groupBy(countFunction)`, which is the same as:

```
words.groupBy(word => countFunction(word))
```

If you cannot change the signature of `countFunction`, then you should be able to call group by like this:

```
words.groupBy(word => countFunction(List(word)))
```

Comment: This worked great. I created a second function that takes in just a word. My other function now just calls this single string function. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the return type of the function in the call. The compiler can figure this out itself. You should just call it like this:

```
words.groupBy(countFunction)
```

If that doesn't work, please post your `countFunction` implementation.

**Update:**

I tested it in the REPL and this works (note that my `countFunction` has a slightly different signature from yours):

```
scala> def isVowel(c: Char) = "aeiou".contains(c)
isVowel: (c: Char)Boolean

scala> def isConsonant(c: Char) = ! isVowel(c)
isConsonant: (c: Char)Boolean

scala> def countFunction(s: String) = (('Consonants, s count isConsonant), ('Vowels, s count isVowel))
countFunction: (s: String)((Symbol, Int), (Symbol, Int))

scala> List("this", "is", "a", "test").groupBy(countFunction)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[((Symbol, Int), (Symbol, Int)),List[java.lang.String]] = Map((('Consonants,0),('Vowels,1)) -> List(a), (('Consonants,1),('Vowels,1)) -> List(is), (('Consonants,3),('Vowels,1)) -> List(this, test))
```

You *can* include the type of the function passed to `groupBy`, but like I said you don't need it. If you want to pass it in you do it like this:

```
words.groupBy(countFunction: String => ((Symbol, Int), (Symbol, Int)))
```